# Rails: How to embed Google Tag Manager for multiple environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables, google-tag-manager

I'm not very familiar with Google Tag Manager ([GTM](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide)) but have been asked to embed its tag into a Rails app. Usually, as with other basic tags, we put the different keys for each environment into a `ENV` variable while the surrounding javascript "tag" remains the same.

However, with [GTM Environments](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6311518?hl=en&ref_topic=9002095) enabled the tag has some additional query strings that don't exist in the "Live" (read: production) version of the tag. See the diff below (dark purple is only in custom staging tag but missing from live (production) tag.

[image: GTM env diff]

I could, obviously, put query string into its own ENV var and just ignore it (and some surrounding syntax `+'…'` in production but this makes me wonder if we might be approaching GTM the wrong way. This is, after all, designed for different environments so why would they go out of their way in the docs to highlight:

> The Environments feature is designed for use with non-production
> environments. To ensure the best performance, you should install the
> standard Tag Manager container snippet on live/production websites.

Forcing us to manage 3 different tags for development, staging and production. Isn't that what a Tag Manager is supposed to do?!?

Anyway, looking for best practices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I only load GTM in production, but my method can be adjusted for all of the environments, using a partial rendered in the HEAD:

```
= render 'shared/google_tag_manager_head' if Rails.env.production?
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wrestling with the same thing.  It sure seems more complicated than it needs to be.

It seems to me that GTM's environments are intended to test changes to your tags within GTM, not as a way to match different tag configurations with different testing environments.  They also require you to vary the code snippet in your HTML to select the GTM environment you want, which seems less than ideal.

I was hoping that GTM variables would be able to differ based on the environment... so that you could use different Google Analytics tracking IDs for each environment.  But, they don't.

This article from 2016 covers several options pretty well: https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2016/05/16/deploying-google-tag-manager-multiple-website-environments/

Based on that article, it seems to me that GTM Lookup Tables are maybe the best option... but, now instead of storing different ENV variables in Heroku, they are embedded in GTM.

UPDATE: I implemented using lookup tables and it worked fine... though, I had to delete my old GA properties and create new GA4 ones.  The old GA tag wouldn't let me choose a variable of type Lookup Table.  It only allowed one of the predefined static property id type.  Once I switched to a "Google Analytics: GA4 Configuration" tag, it allowed me to use the lookup table as the ID.